# MySQL: All parts of primary key must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem with MySQL. I have created Database called 'BucketList', and then I have tried to create table called 'tbl_user', it looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `BucketList`.`tbl_user` (
  `user_id` BIGINT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`));
```

After that I met a problem: "All parts of primary key must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead"

Do you have any idea guys, what's wrong?
MySQL version that I am using is:

```
mysql --version
mysql Ver 14.14  Distrib 5.7.12, for Win64 (x86_64)
```

Comment: Your code works fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6a131.

Comment: What is the **PRIMARY KEY** in the code you posted? `user_id`. How did you define **user_id**? `user_id BIGINT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`. What does the error message say? **All parts of primary key must be NOT NULL**. You don't see a problem with `BIGINT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and **NOT NULL**? Error messages contain useful information (they're not there just to take up screen space), but you have to actually read the words in them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.7, it no longer supports null values for the primary key.

See the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys):

> A unique index where all key columns must be defined as `NOT NULL`. If they are not explicitly declared as `NOT NULL`, MySQL declares them so implicitly (and silently). A table can have only one `PRIMARY KEY`.

So, your `user_id` key cannot be null if it's going to be used as a primary key. You should declare it as non-nullable:

```
CREATE TABLE `BucketList`.`tbl_user` (
  `user_id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`));
```

(Notice the lack of `NULL` after `BIGINT`)

Answer (score 0):

Same this won't work on Mysql 8.0+ as well. The table definition won't accept the criteria of null.

This error occurred when ***not null*** is defined with ***primary key*** column.

Even if you defined any ***composite key***, then those column definition does not contains the ***not null*** criteria.

Search for those column, remove the ***not null*** criteria, this is one of the solution to remove the error.